# NAS vs Microsoft Server: what is the best solution? [solved]

Tags: networking, nas, webserver, windows-server-2008

For my work I need to use different software that run only under windows.

I am unsure whether i should go with a NAS and install this software on the NAS (eg. synology) or consider Microsoft Server Essential

This is the current setting (although it may expand with more software and more users):

- 5 desktops (2 Ubuntu, 2 Win, 1 Mac), 3 laptops (2 Win, 1 Ubuntu), all in different rooms.
- I believe our LAN is wired at 10Gbit.
- NAS or Server would be built with SSD.
- The software is office software, so no graphic or video editing tools
  no more than 2 people accessing the software at any one time
- Beside the software, only office files are planned to be stored on the server (eg. docx, pdf, ...) no videos.
- In general access to software and the files happens onsite but if traveling i may need to access it from remote

How to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having recently purchased a WD NAS I suspect this is all you need. The integrated software typically provides SMB/CIFS access and some models provide NFS for the Linux based systems. Remote access is supported on some models. Having a RAID mirror was important to protect against disk failure (and double read speed).

Check your network, 1G seems more likely than 10G.

Comment: Thanks, what i mean is this: can i install a windows software (eg. solitaire) on the WD NAS (or any network nas in general) and execute it from a laptop? Am I right to say that i can install it on the NAS and create a link from the laptop or the desktop? sort of the NAS become the "shared" C drive where the software is installed and anybody who can connect to that NAS can create and start the software? (Sorry for the wording, I am not an expert on these things).

Comment: Yes, a NAS acts like a network server and and become its own mapped drive. All actions, like running and storing programs, you can do on a local disk can be done on a NAS.